# Smart Map plugin: error sampling 5000 data points

Tags: qgis, sampling

I'm trying to use the Smart-Map plugin in QGIS to do Kriging. I have about 15,300 data points and I need to sample the data (5,000 points, maximum for Smart-Map right now). But this error appears when trying to sample.

Any idea why? (all data certainly float).

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

NameError: name 'float32' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Smart_Map\Smart_Map.py", line 1640, in pushButton_ImportQGIS_clicked
    self.df = self.resampling_of_points(self.df)
  File "C:\Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Smart_Map\Smart_Map.py", line 1130, in resampling_of_points
    features_dense = np.array( features_dense, dtype=float32 )
NameError: name 'float32' is not defined


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.28.3-Firenze Firenze, c12bcb2f76c
```